I couldnt figure out this probability question...
You start with a score of 100 lets call this x. and with equal odds you can get either x+1 or 1/x. you repeat this process 10 times what is your expected score after 10 rounds.
Example: 
So lets say we flip a coin and Heads is x+1 and tails is 1/x. I start with 100 and get heads, so now i have 101, then i get tails and now have 1/101, now i get heads again so i have 1 + 1/101.
I ran a quick simulation in python of (I think) 1000000 simulations to get an idea and got a mean of roughly 10.81.
In order to solve this properly I tried this for now: split the types of scores we can generally have throughout the game into 3 categories:

high numbers (100+),

middle numbers (1 to 10),

and low numbers (<1).


I then looked at the high numbers and realized high numbers can only happen if there is never an odd number of tails consecutively.
For example, HHTT, HHTTHTT, HTTTTH works but HHTHT does not work.

I then tried to figure out the chances of this happening and i tried to solve it using a markov chain of three states:

State E (Even): 
All sequences of tails up to this point have even length, and we're not currently in a run of T's. The last coin flip was heads (H) or we just ended a T run of even length.

State O (Odd): 
We are currently in a run of T's of odd length (we've just seen an odd number of consecutive T's). So we need to get 1 more T to be even.

State F (Failure): 
there has been a finished odd length sequence of Tails.


Now let:

State 0: Even (E)

State 1: Odd (O)

State 2: Failure (F)


set up equations:

from state e: 
$p_n^E = \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1}^E + \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1}^O$

from state o: 
$p_n^O = \frac{1}{2} p_{n-1}^E$


with initial conditions:
$$
p_0^E = 1
p_0^O = 0
$$
solving recursively i found the odds: 89/1024, meaning 89/1024 scores are 100+ which kind of makes sense looking at the code mean of 10.81 considering other possible scores are below 10 down to small decimals.
I then looked at the middle numbers which I think happen when:

a) the last flip is a heads AND

b) the opposite of high numbers, so at least one sequence of odd length of tails.


I could then calculate this similarly to the high numbers and i believe it turns out to be 457/1024 which again makes some sense as scores between 1 and 10 will be more concentrated at 1 as higher scores between 1 and 10 require more consecutive heads leading up to the last round.
However I am not super comfortable with recursion in markov chains, and i am not sure if i took the right approach or if i am climbing up the wrong tree.
That is, assuming I were to find the probabilities for each of the three "score classes", how can I find the EV or some probability distribution etc. for each individual class?
Also for anyone wondering this question was an internship interview question for which I had only pen and paper provided.
We did not have to give the EXACT value, but a rough value, essentially showing the way in detail without doing the technical calculations....

What have you tried so far?

This is confusing: Are "I" and "you" the same person? Also, what is $x$? If it's just one score involved, is this saying that the score either increments by $1$ or gets reciprocalized? So, for instance, from $100$, the score can go to either $101$ or to $0.01$? And, please attend to Chris Lewis's comment and say what you have tried and where you are stuck.

It would be a shame if this question were closed, as it looks quite interesting (the downvotes you've had so far are not from me, by the way). But it's likely to be if you don't add to it a bit. Please include what you've tried and ideally some context; it appears to be a homework question, but it would be useful to know what sort of tools you're expected to use. Are you meant to code this and get an exact answer? Estimate it? Find an algebraic solution?

Also, for anyone downvoting, the person who asked the question is new to the site. It might be useful if you explain why you're downvoting so they can improve the question and ask a better one next time.

Please edit to show some effort.  Suppose you only cared about $1$ round, what's the answer?  What about $2$ rounds?  $3$?

@ChrisLewis thanks a lot for clarifying. To be honest i am very new here and this is my first question. If you have any other question please let me know.

It's a good idea for new posters here to read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

This does not look like a Markov chain. I believe that after ten rounds you have $1024$ different scores each of which is reached by exactly one path, say, $H\dots H\to 110$ and so on. The paths are equally probable but you have to painstakingly determine the $1024$ scores to calculate your expectation. Take just a few rounds. Doing this for ten rounds is just making the exercise duller.

The poster has improved the question. Can this be considered for reopening, please?

@KurtG. so would you say the only way to calculate this is by determining the 1024 scores (i.e. all combinations of flips)?

This is what I said I believe. Looking at fewer rounds will show the pattern. If you want the post to be reopened you can also reduce it in size focusing on math.

@KurtG. I agree that listing out the 1024 cases is tedious (impractical by hand, trivial but uninformative by code). I wonder if there's any way to estimate the result? I actually think OP's approach of looking at different ranges of scores and the point you jump from one to another is pretty interesting.

@ChrisLewis I don't think OP's sentence "realized high numbers can only happen if there is never an odd number of tails consecutively" makes a lot of sense. I am simply too lazy  to work on this when OP already solved it by a python simulation.

@KurtG. Would you say there is no other way to calculate the probabilities for those three classes other than calculating them explicitly 1 by 1? or are you saying there is no use for this and it would not help with the final solution as we cannot know the probability distribution for the individual classes without solving explicitly? Also the python simulation or calculating explicitly may solutions but would it not be more interesting to solve some other way?

@ChrisLewis : "I agree that listing out the 1024 cases is tedious (impractical by hand, trivial but uninformative by code)." : I moderately disagree.  You can set $~n \in {1,2,3,\cdots,20},~$ and for each value of $~n,~$ examine the results for each of the $~2^n~$ possible paths.  Further, for each value of $~n,~$ you can set $~x \in {1,10,100,1000}.~$  So, you end up with a 2 dimensional [n::x] chart of exact values.  Then, you can study the data, try to find a pattern in the data, try to construct a hypothesis based on the perceived pattern, and then try to prove the hypothesis.

Too long for a comment.
def get_bit( number, position ):
    return( number >> position ) & 1

X = list()

sum = 0
for n in range(1024):
    x = 100
    for i in range(10):
        if get_bit(n,i) == 1:
           x += 1
        else:
           x = 1/x
     sum += x
     X.append(x)
 average = sum/1024
 print( "Average score {:f}".format( average ) )


This python program calculates the average exactly (no simulation):  $10.812677\,.$
There are only $249$ different scores. Analyse the list X to see their distribution. It has a large peak at very small values and a smaller peak between $100$ and the maximum $110\,.$ Between $10$ and $99$ there is a large region of no scores.

